# Django project with various apps how is top level models?

Tags: django

> settings.py

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'food',
    'nursing',
    'shopping',
    'stay',
    'tourism',
    'transportation',
    'treatment',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

There is a specific model in each 7 applications `models.py`.

How is creating master top level of that may in project folder to inheriting with applications specific model? (How all project's applications inherit from an overall model with common fields?)

I have tried:

```
inner_project_directory/
  --_pycache__
  --_init__.py
  --app.py
  --asgi.py
  --models.py
  --settings.py   # I have created top master level in project folder
  --urls.py
```

Encountered with:

> raise RuntimeError(
>
> RuntimeError: Model class projectfolder.models.User doesn't declare an
> explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

**What is the right approach for implementing top level model with most common fields which is inheriting in project applications?**

Comment: Would be better to create a `common` app, so you can store common things, as well as base model there. And import as `from common.models import BaseModel`... `class MyModel(BaseModel):`. P.S. Do not forget to use `abstract = True` in base model to not create redundant tables in the database.

Comment: @VitaliiVolkov, As your answer, I can implement *common* app to have common template and statics and common etc, Thank you.